# Is wiring ADSL and Phone lines to a patch panel ok?

Tags: adsl, wiring, networking

Is it OK to wire an POTS line + ADSL line directly into a patch panel?

I guess I'm wondering as well why do regular phone jacks have some passive electronic parts inside them.  Since wiring it straight onto a patch panel would not have those passives.

Yet I have seen this done before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this myself at home. It's a great way of getting a POTS line somewhere else.

I've never seen a phone jack with any passive parts inside them - only an RJ11 connector.

Comment: Most of the jacks in NZ homes have some passive parts inside. Looks like a cap. Can't recall what else.

Comment: Found a link on a NZ website where someone was doing just this.  Sounds like it's OK.  Still not sure what the passives are for.

Comment: Interesting. Is this inside an RJ11 socket, or one of those stupid 605 plugs (http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=NUk&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&q=605+plug&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1920&bih=921)?

Comment: No.  NZ has BT style.  I found an interesting link here.  It describes what the passives are for in the master socket.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_telephone_sockets#Master_socket_and_NTE-5_Line_Box

Comment: Looks like it's OK.  I think the passives are for the old standard.  http://www.telepermit.co.nz/PTC106_Mar_2008.pdf

Comment: NZ imported their automated exchanges from the UK and swapped the pulse dialing order. As for wiring into patch panels, it's pretty standard practice to run directly from the distribution frame to the patch panel (possibly via a PABX).